# SQL Server : Counts/Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have an `orders` table that I need to generate a report from that groups by month/year, showing the total orders for the month, and the number actually received.

This gives me total # of orders by month/year:

```
SELECT YEAR(o.OrderDate) As 'Year'
    , MONTH(o.OrderDate) As 'Month'
    , COUNT(ID) As 'OrderCount'
FROM Orders o 
GROUP BY YEAR(o.OrderDate), MONTH (o.OrderDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(o.OrderDate) DESC, MONTH (o.OrderDate) DESC
```

This gives me total # of orders RECEIVED by month/year:

```
SELECT YEAR(o.OrderDate) As 'Year'
    , MONTH(o.OrderDate) As 'Month'
    , COUNT(o.ID) As 'OrderReceivedCount'
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderStatus s ON s.ID = o.CurrentStatus 
WHERE s.StatusPriority > 4 AND s.IsCancelled = 0
GROUP BY YEAR(o.OrderDate), MONTH (o.OrderDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(o.OrderDate) DESC, MONTH (o.OrderDate) DESC
```

But how can I combine that into one query? I can't work out how the 'group by' would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
SELECT YEAR(o.OrderDate) As [Year]
    , MONTH(o.OrderDate) As [Month]
    , COUNT(*) As OrderCount
    , SUM(CASE
            WHEN s.StatusPriority > 4 AND
                 s.IsCancelled = 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END) as OrderReceivedCount
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderStatus s ON s.ID = o.CurrentStatus 
GROUP BY YEAR(o.OrderDate), MONTH (o.OrderDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(o.OrderDate) DESC, MONTH (o.OrderDate) DESC
```

That is join all of the orders to their statuses, whatever they may be, and then do a conditional count of those (via `SUM/CASE`) to work out which ones have been received.